# Python pandas dataframe select rows from columns

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, rows

In an Excel sheet with columns Rainfall / Year / Month, I want to sum rainfall data per year. That is, for instance, for the year 2000, from month 1 to 12, summing all the Rainfall cells into a new one.
I tried using pandas in Python but cannot manage (just started coding). How can I proceed? Any help is welcome, thanks!

Here the head of the data (which has been downloaded):

```
   rainfall (mm)  \tyear   month  country   iso3   iso2
0      120.54000    1990       1      ECU    NaN    NaN
1      231.15652    1990       2      ECU    NaN    NaN
2      136.62088    1990       3      ECU    NaN    NaN
3      203.47653    1990       4      ECU    NaN    NaN
4      164.20956    1990       5      ECU    NaN    NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and aggregate `sum` if need sum of all years:

```
df = df.groupby('\tyear')['rainfall (mm)'].sum()
```

But if need only one value:

```
df.loc[df['\tyear'] == 2000, 'rainfall (mm)'].sum()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the year 2000, use

```
df[df['\tyear'] == 2000]['rainfall (mm)'].sum()
```

Otherwise, jezrael's answer is nice because it sums `rainfall (mm)` for each distinct value of `\tyear`.